# Hyperlinks not working in user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed

After the migration, it appears that the hyperlinks in my profile description are no longer working.  I've noticed the same problem with some other users who I seem to recall had working hyperlinks before.  I see that the *website* field is still working properly, but inline hyperlinks seem to be broken for most users.  I did notice that some users still have working hyperlinks, for example Vidit Nanda has a working link to the Math Genealogy Project.

> Have other users noticed the same phenomenon, or is this perhaps a browser-based problem on my part (I am using Chrome)?
>
> Is there an easy fix for this if the problem is indeed real?

Comment: Have you tried editing in the links?  The About Me section of the profile should support [Markdown links](http://mathoverflow.net/editing-help#links).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like all of the links in your profile were marked with a "nofollow" attribute, which in turn told our engine to stop rendering them as links.

This is *probably* a side-effect of your other site profiles having lower reputation and MathOverflow joining the SE network. ("nofollow"ing links from new-ish accounts is in place to prevent the less scrupulous folks from creating profiles and using them to set up a link farm.)

I edited your profile to remove the "nofollow" attributes and copied your profile to your other sites as well. All the links should be working as expected now. Please let us know if this happens again for some reason and we'll dig into it further.

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch for your help!